# PHPExcel Load image from outside URL

Tags: image, url, phpexcel

Does anyone know how to make setPath() method able to load an image from outside server? Because all images is store on other server.I don't have any idea how to do that. Please help me. thanks

```
<pre>
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setPath('http://domain.com/images/testing.jpg');
$objDrawing->setHeight(96);
$objDrawing->setOffsetX(27);
$objDrawing->setOffsetY(40);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A9');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($this->excel->getActiveSheet());
</pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

Images can't be referenced from a URL, you need the image in your local filesystem because PHPExcel needs to extract information from that image. Use curl (or even `file_get_contents()`) to pull the image to the local filesystem first. Once the image has been embedded in the Excel document, you can delete the file again.

Answer (score -2):

You can put false as the second option in the `setPath()` method. Tcpdf gets the image from the URL and PHPExcel doesn't throw an exception.